# My question, being very broad, attracted a lot of answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

I recently put a question up about computers that had more than one CPU. In hindsight I see this question is very broad, and that's why it has attracted a lot of short answers. And so it has been protected.

What I had in mind was a computer which contained two or more general purpose CPUs. Many of the answers talk about computers which have and CPU and a DSP, and one comment mentions the Copper chip from the Amiga chipset so show that the question could at least define what I meant a bit better.

And many answers also describe computers which have two CPUs but could only run one at a time, such as the DEC Rainbow 100 or the SuperPET.

If I edit this question now, I could invalidate some of these answers. Should I go ahead and do that though?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for asking this as it relates to an issue that we as a community need to decide upon.

Firstly, to your specific point, I don't believe that editing your question to reduce the scope would make a material difference.  It would still be broad.

So, yes, your question is broad and is essentially asking for a list.  It is not the first such question on the site, for example: [What early computers had excellent BASIC (or other language) at bootup?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1986/276)

List questions do not make a good fit with the StackExchange model of question and specific answer.  Indeed they are explicitly off-topic at some sites, although other sites permit them.  The wider question is whether we want such questions on the site.

We are a young site and have let the small number of list questions ride so far.   They have brought new members to the site and helped it keep growing.  We need to consider whether we continue to accept them or become more rigorous at closing as *too broad*.